Windows Property Pages: Domain Path Not Shown on Security Tab
When I want to set security permissions on a file or some other object, I need to open its property dialog end select the security tab. In order to add a domain user to set her permissions on the object, I can only select users or groups from the machine but not from the domain I'm logged on to (even as an admin). In the dialog which shows up to allow me to select users, the domain path is not shown and thus cannot be selected.
This is irrrespective of how long ago I've started the machine. I am able to access a domain server so connectivity is unlikely to be the reason. Environment is Windows 11 / Windows Server 2022. Any idea?

Meanwhile, I found the reason:DNS queries within my Windows domain are performed using IPv6 only on my machines, ignoring the corresponding IPv4 settings in this case. In the netcard settings for the IPv6 protocol, "Automatic settings" was selected, but in the Extended dialog's DNS tab, there were no DNS server address entries on those machines which exposed the problem. After entering a server address, everything works fine now.

Note as a takeaway: The DNS settings for IPv4 are apparently ignored within a Windows domain, at least when IPv6 is activated which usually the case on more recent Windows versions.

Most probable reason might be a group policy setting (Do not enumerate connected users on domain-joined computers) is applied to your computer. You may verify with rsop.msc console OR gpresult -z from cmd line on the computer that this policy is applied. Since this is a computer policy, it applies to all users (local or domain) logging onto that computer.

Thank you. This setting is not enabled, so by default, connected users on domain-joined computers should be visible. However, an administrator should always be able to see domain users be they connected or not. Therefore, I don't think that this setting is related to my problem.

Group policy applies to administrators also (including Domain Admins) if they are in scope. If you do not find any group policy setting related to enumeration, I would recommend: 1) using nltest /sc_query:, test your secure channel of the computer and the DC.


Add-NTFSAccess .\Data -> \user1 Rights Modify -AppliesTo ThisFolderOnly. Using a similar test command from powershell, can you add a domain user permission to the file?


File access is an example only. The same problem occurs when I want to add an account to a database system.
